# InterfaceError sqlite Error binding parameter 0

Tags: python, sqlite, parameters, binding

This is the code:

```
 temp=[[aberturas],[fechamentos], [highs], [lows], [volumes], [medias], [data_str]]
    conexao=sqlite3.connect("negociacao.db")
    conexao.row_factory=sqlite3.Row
    cursor=conexao.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
                    create table if not exists negociacao(
                    id integer primary key autoincrement,
                    Open float,
                    Close float,
                    High float,
                    Low float,
                    Volume float,
                    Media float,
                    Data date)''')
    cursor.executemany('''
                        insert into negociacao(Open,Close,High,Low,Volume,Media,Data)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(temp,))
    conexao.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conexao.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\laura.correia\Downloads\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App\All\API_Negociacao.py", line 179, in <module>
    insert into negociacao(Open,Close,High,Low,Volume,Media,Data)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',(temp,))
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type
```

Comment: The `seq_of_parameters` argument of [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) must be a sequence of sequences or mappings. _This_: `cursor.executemany(<sql string>, (temp,))` is a sequence of sequences of sequences. You'd need to pass  temp` directly: `cursor.execute(<sql string>, temp)`. That will raise another error, because your query string has seven bindings and your `temp` provides just one per query. It should have this structure: `temp = [[2.34, 2.45, 2.51, 2.37, 1000, 2, "2018-12-10"], [7.34, 7.45, 7.51, 7.37, 1000, 2, "2018-12-10"]]`

Comment: can you explain better the stucture of temp, didn't understand what you did

Comment: Your query has seven paramter bindings, you need a sequence (e.g. a list or tuple) of seven values to execute your query, e.g. `[2.34, 2.45, 2.51, 2.37, 1000, 2, "2018-12-10"]` providing values for `Open, Close, High, Low, Volume, Media and Data`. If you use `executemany` you want to execute the same query with multiple sets of parameters. That means you must pass a list or tuple of such sequences. `temp = [[2.34, 2.45, 2.51, 2.37, 1000, 2, "2018-12-10"], [7.34, 7.45, 7.51, 7.37, 1000, 2, "2018-12-10"]]` will insert two rows into `negociacao`, each defined by one of the inner lists in `temp`.

Comment: I did this  cursor.execute('''create table if not exists negociacao(id integer primary key autoincrement,temp)''') now the error is gone but my table is empty

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(type(temp[0]))`. Compare the  output with the `type` of your **first** Column in the `insert ... Open float,...` statement. Means `type(temp[0])` must be `float`, and so on for all Columns.

Comment: the result was <type 'list'>

Comment: How did you come up with the change to your **CREATE TABLE** statement as a fix for the error with parameter substitution while executing your **INSERT** statement?